# Registry tweaks for devices running Windows 10 mobile

Tags: windows-10-mobile

After discovering it was possible to change screen lock options on my Lumia 950 with the interlop tools and registry editor recently, I went looking for more tweaks. 
I didn't find many.

Considering that there are so many aspects of W10 mobile that could be improved, does anyone have registry tweaks they'd like to share?

It would be great to compile a definitive list..

Cheers.

Comment: Maybe see if someone on xda-develppers has some ideas.

Comment: I've checked XDA developers for posts on the subject, but perhaps I should make a post there too. I rather hoped this would be where the windows experts are!